# Getting my radio buttons to display under the canvas for tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a program which creates a traffic light, I have the program all set and it works properly but I have a minor issue with the formatting. I want the radio buttons to be on the bottom the "traffic light", not the top.

```
from tkinter import *

class TrafficLight:

    def __init__(self):

        window = Tk()
        window.title("Traffic Light")

        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack()

        self.color = StringVar()

        rbRed = Radiobutton(frame, text = "Red", variable = self.color, value = "R", command = self.colorChange)
        rbRed.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        rbYellow = Radiobutton(frame, text = "Yellow", variable = self.color, value = "Y", command = self.colorChange)
        rbYellow.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        rbGreen = Radiobutton(frame, text = "Green", variable = self.color, value = "G", command = self.colorChange)
        rbGreen.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 80, height = 180, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.red = self.canvas.create_oval(20,20,60,60, fill = "white")
        self.yellow = self.canvas.create_oval(20,70,60,110, fill = "white")
        self.green = self.canvas.create_oval(20,120,60,160, fill = "white")

        window.mainloop()

    def colorChange(self):
        on = self.color.get()

        if on == "R":
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.red, fill = "red")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.yellow, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.green, fill = "white")
        elif on == "Y":
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.red, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.yellow, fill = "yellow")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.green, fill = "white")
        elif on == "G":
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.red, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.yellow, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.green, fill = "green")
```

It looks like this:

[image: My traffic light when run]

Comment: I'll leave it up but I figured it out myself. I just put the frame and frame.pack() after the self.canvas.pack(). Just needed some rearranging

Comment: Normally, you would supply some arguments to your ``.pack()`` calls (``.pack(side='bottom')``, perhaps), to control where they get packed relative to other widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `pack()` this is placed in the initial part, you must change the order.

```
from tkinter import *

class TrafficLight:

    def __init__(self):

        window = Tk()
        window.title("Traffic Light")

        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 80, height = 180, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack()

        self.color = StringVar()

        rbRed = Radiobutton(frame, text = "Red", variable = self.color, value = "R", command = self.colorChange)
        rbRed.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        rbYellow = Radiobutton(frame, text = "Yellow", variable = self.color, value = "Y", command = self.colorChange)
        rbYellow.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        rbGreen = Radiobutton(frame, text = "Green", variable = self.color, value = "G", command = self.colorChange)
        rbGreen.grid(row = 1, column = 3)


        self.red = self.canvas.create_oval(20,20,60,60, fill = "white")
        self.yellow = self.canvas.create_oval(20,70,60,110, fill = "white")
        self.green = self.canvas.create_oval(20,120,60,160, fill = "white")

        window.mainloop()

    def colorChange(self):
        on = self.color.get()

        if on == "R":
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.red, fill = "red")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.yellow, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.green, fill = "white")
        elif on == "Y":
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.red, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.yellow, fill = "yellow")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.green, fill = "white")
        elif on == "G":
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.red, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.yellow, fill = "white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.green, fill = "green")

TrafficLight()
```

[image]